# Google App Engine api throws 503, but error not shown in the admin console

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have deployed my project in Google App Engine, python using API endpoints. The API calls made from AngularJS throws a 503. But when I look through into the admin console it shows the status as 200. If the same API is called once again with same parameters it does not throw an error and it works perfectly fine. The quota limit is set to "unlimited". Attaching the screenshot of the response.

[image: 503_error_response]

Comment: totally weired.. Pls  refresh the console.. You can filter the request logs by error.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I tried doing that. But it does not show any error.

Comment: pls check the url you actually gave in the angular project.. whether it's referring to stagging or production or local..

Comment: I've seen random, unlogged 503 errors as well, from an Android client in my case, and using Java on the server. My assumption is that they're introduced between an outside-facing server and the server that actually handles your request, that's why you're not seeing it in the log. On mobile I retry most failing requests anyway due to unreliable connectivity, so it's not such a big deal to realize that AppEngine is not dependable. If you ever get to the bottom of it, please update us on your findings.